# Flutter / Dart - parse json time series as map with key and value

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, key

I encountered the below message on "anonymous closure" in the TimeSeriesAdjusted.fromJson which I think may be the issue but I could not figure where may have gone wrong.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
#0      new PriceData.fromJson (package:flutter_app_watchlist/model/TimeSeriesAdjusted.dart:60:28)
#1      new TimeSeriesAdjusted.fromJson. *****anonymous closure>** (package:flutter_app_watchlist/model/TimeSeriesAdjusted.dart:87:116)
#2      MapMixin.map (dart:collection/maps.dart:170:28)
#3      new TimeSeriesAdjusted.fromJson (package:flutter_app_watchlist/model/TimeSeriesAdjusted.dart:87:62)
#4      getData (package:flutter_app_watchlist/main.dart:21:52)
*****asynchronous suspension>**
```

Below is the time series json (saved as data.json in folder assets) which I would like to parse.

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
    "2. Symbol": "IBM",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-06-07",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2021-06-07": {
      "1. open": "147.55",
      "2. high": "148.74",
      "3. low": "147.17",
      "4. close": "148.02",
      "5. adjusted close": "148.02",
      "6. volume": "3462712",
      "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
      "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
    },
    "2021-06-04": {
      "1. open": "146.0",
      "2. high": "147.55",
      "3. low": "145.76",
      "4. close": "147.42",
      "5. adjusted close": "147.42",
      "6. volume": "3117905",
      "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
      "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
    },
    "2021-06-03": {
      "1. open": "144.91",
      "2. high": "145.88",
      "3. low": "144.04",
      "4. close": "145.55",
      "5. adjusted close": "145.55",
      "6. volume": "4130741",
      "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
      "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
    },
    "2021-06-02": {
      "1. open": "144.62",
      "2. high": "145.75",
      "3. low": "144.11",
      "4. close": "145.72",
      "5. adjusted close": "145.72",
      "6. volume": "2786916",
      "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
      "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
    },
    "2021-06-01": {
      "1. open": "145.0",
      "2. high": "145.83",
      "3. low": "143.75",
      "4. close": "144.19",
      "5. adjusted close": "144.19",
      "6. volume": "2417455",
      "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
      "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

getData() async {
  String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
  TimeSeriesAdjusted jsonData = TimeSeriesAdjusted.fromJson(json.decode(data));
  print(jsonData.toString());
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  getData();
} // main


class TimeSeriesMetaData {
  final String information; // "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events"
  final String symbol; // "2. Symbol": "IBM"
  final String lastRefreshed; // "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-06-07"
  final String outputSize; // "4. Output Size": "Compact"
  final String timezone; // "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"

  TimeSeriesMetaData({
    required this.information,
    required this.symbol,
    required this.lastRefreshed,
    required this.outputSize,
    required this.timezone});

  factory TimeSeriesMetaData.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return TimeSeriesMetaData(
        information: json["1. Information"],
        symbol: json["2. Symbol"],
        lastRefreshed: json["3. Last Refreshed"],
        outputSize: json["4. Output Size"],
        timezone: json["5. Time Zone"]);
  } // factory TimeSeriesMetaData.fromJson

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'TimeSeriesMetaData: {1. Information = $information, '
        '2. Symbol = $symbol, '
        '3. Last Refreshed = $lastRefreshed, '
        '4. Output Size = $outputSize, '
        '5. Time Zone = $timezone, }';
  } // toString
} // class TimeSeriesMetaData

class PriceData {
  final String open; // "1. open": "147.55"
  final String high; // "2. high": "148.74"
  final String low; // "3. low": "147.17"
  final String close; // "4. close": "148.02"
  final String adjustedClose; // "5. adjusted close": "148.02"
  final String volume; // "6. volume": "3462712"
  final String dividendAmount; // "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
  final String splitCoefficient; // "8. split coefficient": "1.0"

  PriceData({
    required this.open,
    required this.high,
    required this.low,
    required this.close,
    required this.adjustedClose,
    required this.volume,
    required this.dividendAmount,
    required this.splitCoefficient});

  factory PriceData.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return PriceData(
        open: json["1. open"],
        high: json["2. high"],
        low: json["3. low"],
        close: json["4. close"],
        adjustedClose: json["5. adjustedClose"],
        volume: json["6. volume"],
        dividendAmount: json["7. dividendAmount"],
        splitCoefficient: json["8. splitCoefficient"]);
  } // factory TimeSeriesMetaData.fromJson

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PriceData: {1. open = $open, 2. high = $high, '
        '3. low = $low, 4. close = $close, 5. adjustedClose = $adjustedClose, '
        '6. volume = $volume, 7. dividendAmount = $dividendAmount, '
        '8. splitCoefficient = $splitCoefficient}';
  } // toString
} // class TimeSeriesMetaData

class TimeSeriesAdjusted {
  final TimeSeriesMetaData timeSeriesMetaData;
  final Map<String, PriceData> timeSeriesDaily;

  TimeSeriesAdjusted({
    required this.timeSeriesMetaData, // security symbol e.g. IBM
    required this.timeSeriesDaily, // security type e.g. common stock
  });

  factory TimeSeriesAdjusted.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TimeSeriesAdjusted(
      timeSeriesMetaData: TimeSeriesMetaData.fromJson(json["Meta Data"]),
      timeSeriesDaily: Map.from(json["Time Series (Daily)"]).map((k,v) => MapEntry<String, PriceData>(k, PriceData.fromJson(v))),
    );
  } // fromJson - extract from Json

  @override
  String toString() {
    //return 'TimeSeriesAdjusted: $timeSeriesMetaData';
    return 'TimeSeriesAdjusted: $timeSeriesMetaData, $timeSeriesDaily';
  } // toString

} // class TimeSeriesAdjusted
```

Answer (score 0):

ah... i realised where the mistake lies.. i got the attribute name incorrect in PriceData.fromJson when i called json['xxx]. below corrected for 5, 7, 8

```
 factory PriceData.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return PriceData(
        open: json["1. open"],
        high: json["2. high"],
        low: json["3. low"],
        close: json["4. close"],
        adjustedClose: json["5. adjusted close"],
        volume: json["6. volume"],
        dividendAmount: json["7. dividend amount"],
        splitCoefficient: json["8. split coefficient"]);
  } // factory TimeSeriesMetaData.fromJson
```